# What kind of figurative language is this phrase?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, figures-of-speech, figurative

What figurative language is "to drive the idea out of my mind"? Is it an idiom or personification? Or something else? I have tried to figure it out but I can't.

The full sentence is:

> He wanted to drive the idea of studying Kabbalah from my mind.

(From *Night* by Elie Wiesel)

Comment: Which of these seems like the fundamental, basic sense of 'drive / driving'? He's driving me mad. / The hammer is quickly driving the nails into the soft wood. / Various factors are driving house prices up. / He's driving a hard bargain. The basic (physical) usage here is literal, the rest are metaphorical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No I meant "He wanted to drive the idea of studying Kabbalah from my mind. In vain." A short sentence in Night by Elie Wiesel. So sort of like "He's driving me mad" I think? I don't know English is not my best subject. And could you explain what literal usage is? Haha I'm sorry

Comment: A quick check in [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drive) gives this list of senses: 1. To push, propel, or press onward forcibly; urge forward: [drove the nail into the post] drove the horses into the corral. 2. To repulse or put to flight by force or influence: drove the attackers away; drove out any thought of failure. (I've added a further example.) Notice that they give the 'physical', observable-by-eye examples first. This is true also with Collins, RHK Webster's and doubtless other dictionaries. The **metaphorical** usages ('drove out any thought' ...) are given later.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is figurative.  See entry **3b** from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive)

*" to repulse, remove, or cause to go by force, authority, or influence "*

Comment: I agree; none the less, I picture driving fat, dumb birds from a field, or driving a herd of beasts over a cliff.

Comment: @DanBron Perhaps driving a dumb bird out of a field **is** equivalent to driving a dumb idea out of your head!

Answer (score 0):

**What figurative language is "to drive the idea out of my mind"?**

**drive out** can be idiomatic  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drive+out)

> 2. To force or entice *someone* or *something* to *leave some place*. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between "drive" and "out."

As in your question.  Here is another example:

*What can we do to drive these troublesome demons out of your mind?*

Answer (score -2):

That is personification due to the fact that ideas cannot drive and humans/people can

Comment: That would depend on what the rest of the sentence is (which is given in a comment). "He wanted to drive the idea of studying Kabbalah from my mind." is not personification. (I've edited the question to be clearer, and you should edit your answer.)

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its length and content." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - for example, adding a dictionary definition as support for your proposed solution, linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)